# Interrupting an ongoing NSURLConnection

Tags: ios

I have a `UIProgressView` custom class (`UIDownloadbar` at github [here](https://github.com/sakrist/UIDownloadBar)) and I was trying to add a feature to this class to interrupt all a downloads. I thus added a shared instance of this type:

```
+ (UIDownloadBar *)sharedInstance {
    static UIDownloadBar *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[UIDownloadBar alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

+(void)forceStopForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{
    UIDownloadBar *storeManager = [UIDownloadBar sharedInstance];
    [storeManager forceStopForIdentifier:identifier];
}

- (void)forceStopForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{
    operationBreaked = YES;
    stopString = @"stop";
}
```

The code works just fine, the `stopString` values changed to stop. However it does not seem to change the data in download method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"value of string: %@", stopString);
    if (![stopString isEqualToString:@"stop"]) {

        [self.receivedData appendData:data];

    float receivedLen = [data length];
    bytesReceived = (bytesReceived + receivedLen);

    if(expectedBytes != NSURLResponseUnknownLength) {
        self.progress = ((bytesReceived/(float)expectedBytes)*100)/100;
        percentComplete = self.progress*100;
    }
    //NSLog(@" Data receiving... Percent complete: %f", percentComplete);

    [delegate downloadBarUpdated:self];

    } else {
        [connection cancel];
        NSLog(@" STOP !!!!  Receiving data was stoped");
    }

}
```

According to the `NSLog` the value of the string (or of the BOOL or whatever) I use to identify the change, does not change. It is fixed to the original value, even if it **has changed**!

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The two parts of code you posted don't have any relation. Did you forget to add the `downloadBarUpdated` code ?

Comment: I do have it, but I can't stop the connection from that method

Comment: I see, you are working with internet connection at the view class. Then you need to provide more details.